# SSEx with a only 1.25x speed boost

Tags: c++, sse

a newbie in coding, really need your advice......

Recently I'm been trying some SSE coding to speed up simple calculations (addition and multiplication), I've been told there will be a 2x more speed boost with SSEx. But my result shows only a 1.25x boost, is there anything wrong with my code?

I've tried declaring the input arrays as global variables to maintain address continuity,not using local variables in SSE part, both in vain.

The following is the code,compiling with
g++ -mfpath=sse -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse4.1 -O -Wall test.c

```
#define N 32768
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>  //sse4.1
#include <emmintrin.h> //sse2
#include <xmmintrin.h> //sse 
#include <mmintrin.h> //mmx
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void init_with_rand(float *array);



float input1[N];
float input2[N];
float input3[N];
float output1[N];
float output2[N];
__m128 A,B,C,MUX,SUM;

int main(void)
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    int i,j;

    init_with_rand(input1);
    init_with_rand(input2);
    init_with_rand(input3);

    t1 = clock();
    for(j = 0; j < 1000000; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){ 
            output1[i] = input1[i] * input2[i] + input3[i];
        }
    }
    t1 = clock()-t1;
    printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t1,((float)t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    t2 = clock();
    for(j = 0; j < 1000000; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < N; i+=4){
        A = _mm_load_ps(input1+i);
        B = _mm_load_ps(input2+i);
        C = _mm_load_ps(input3+i);
        MUX = _mm_mul_ps(A, B);
        SUM = _mm_add_ps( MUX , C);
        _mm_store_ps(output2+i, SUM);
        }
    }
    t2 = clock()-t2;
    printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t2,((float)t2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    printf ("Performance is increased by %f times.\n",((float)t1/(float)t2));

    if(!memcmp(output1,output2,N))
        printf("Valid\n");
    else if(memcmp(output1,output2,N))
        printf("Invalid\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");
    return 0;
}

void init_with_rand(float *array)
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++)
        array[i] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);

}
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Why only `-O`, and not `-O3`?  No point in comparing speed unless you use at least `-O2`.  Also, you should prefer using `-march=nehalem` or something if you want to target and tune for a specific CPU microarchitecture.  `-march=native` targets your current CPU.  Of course, like other `-m` options, this can make a binary that doesn't work on older CPUs.

Comment: also new to SSE but wondering if it's an option to use the functions like this: `SUM = _mm_mul_ps(A, B); SUM = _mm_add_ps( SUM , C);` - that is, more like registers / accumulators? if it's possible this way you can remove two SSE vectors out of the process but i don't know if that's an improvement. or for that matter which is better (or even legal) - loading all at once or as-needed for `A,B,C`. Eg is `Load A,B,C; SUM=A+B; MUL=SUM*C` is faster than `Load R=input1,T=input2; R+=T; Load T=input3; R*=T` ?

Comment: Why are you mocking up your own profiler, and optimising a mock? Optimisations are specific to bottlenecks, which are specific to programs. For a start you need a REAL profiler and a program that solves a real problem and has a bottleneck that is realistically too slow for people. You should also be hand-optimising code that is fully machine-optimised at this stage, as explained in a different topic. Is it possible that the "2x" is a historical figure or exaggeration? Optimisations for compilers improve over time, and sometimes some people lie...

Comment: I hope your intentions are to profile your programs to determine the most significant bottlenecks, optimise those and then profile again to prove success, as opposed to writing code that you've previously proven to be fast using these mocks, because you need to optimise **your time** and **ability to maintain the code**, not just the speed of your code. If you take too long to write messy (but "fast", "but I haven't profiled it before and after as proof") code, your employer will find someone else... remember that. Only optimise when told "it's too slow", and use a profiler!

Comment: @PeterCordes, I would argue that in this case `-O3` is need due to auto-vectorization (or `-O2` with a autovectorization flag as well).  `-O2` would not be a fair test.

Comment: @XerenNarcy: Yes, you can use the same variable as an input and output to an intrinsic.  It doesn't matter though; the compiler will turn it all into an internal representation of the data flow (like SSA) where variable names don't matter, and then will choose how to allocate things to registers.  It doesn't matter how many different variable names you have (as long as you compile with optimizations and don't do anything terrible like use global variables as temporaries.)  You can put the code on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to easily look at the asm.